# Turn Exploded text file into table

Tags: php, mysql, cron, exploded

I'm running speedtest-cli on a Linux box, with a Cron job to run it regularly:

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> /home/blob/speedtest.log
/usr/local/bin/speedtest --simple >> /home/blob/speedtest.log
```

This outputs four variables, with line breaks between each:

```
Tue 31 Jan 20:00:01 UTC 2017
Ping: xx.xxx ms
Download: xx.xx Mbit/s
Upload: xx.xx Mbit/s
```

These are stored in a continuous log file.

I'm trying to store it in a five column - ID, date, ping, download, upload - database, such that I can run the cron job, read the result to the database, and then truncate the log file (so it doesn't have duplicates):

```
<body>
<table>

<?php
    $f = fopen("/home/blob/speedtest.log", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    $arr_to_insert = array();
    // Read line by line until end of file
    while (!feof($f)) { 

    // Make an array using line break as delimiter
       $arrEx = explode('\n',fgets($f)); 
    // Put exploded data in an array
       echo '<tr><td name="date">' . $arrEx[0] . '</td><td name="ping">' . $arrEx[1] . '</td><td name="download">' . $arrEx[2] . '</td><td name="upload">' . $arrEx[3] . '</td></tr>';
       //strore text file row to an array 
       $arr_to_insert[] = $arrEx;
    }

    fclose($f);
 {

    // Connect to Database
include '../includes/connection.php';
    // Database Insert
foreach($arr_to_insert as $di){
    $sql="INSERT INTO speed (date, ping, download, upload) VALUES ('{$di[0]}','{$di[1]}','{$di[2]}','{$di[3]}')";
    if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
      }

}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Which does store the data - so no error messages - but all in the one column, rather than each cron job populating a single row; date goes in date, ping in ping, etc.

```
ID  date    ping    download    upload
1   Sat 28 Jan          
2   Ping: xx            
3   Download: xx            
4   Upload: xx          
5   Sat 28 Jan          
6   Ping: xx            
7   Download: xx
```

Could someone please point out why it's not populating the table after exploding, and subsequently being stored in the database correctly. 
Thanks

Comment: I belive the explode function doesn't work right and all the row is still in "{$di[0]}" which insert its value to the first column. Can you share the output of "var_dump($arrEx);"?

Comment: I think you're right. Even without a var_dump, I can see from the source when the code runs it's only the date field that gets filled:

'<table>
<tbody><tr><td><name="date">Sat 28 Jan 22:30:01 UTC 2017
</td>
<td><name="ping"></td><td><name="download"></td><td><name="upload"></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td>
<name="date">Ping: 36.209 ms
</td><td><name="ping"></td><td><name="download"></td><td><name="upload"></td></tr></tbody>' etc

Comment: Now we need the var_dump to understand why the explode function does work as you've expected it to be.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "Sat 28 Jan 22:30:01 UTC 2017 " } array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Ping: 36.209 ms " } array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "Download: 41.43 Mbit/s " } array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "Upload: 9.74 Mbit/s " } array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "Sat 28 Jan 22:45:01 UTC 2017 " } array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Ping: 28.675 ms " } array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "Download: 46.67 Mbit/s " } array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Upload: 10.86 Mbit/s " }

Comment: Can you copy the first 20 lines of the .log file in a CODE block in your question?

Comment: I understood the problem. writing a solution.

Comment: When you say the first 20 lines, that's just the 4 lines at the top of the question repeated 5 times, right?
Edit: Just seen your subsequent reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log files contains the following:

> Tue 31 Jan 20:00:01 UTC 2017
>
> Ping: xx.xxx ms
>
> Download: xx.xx Mbit/s
>
> Upload: xx.xx Mbit/s
>
> Tue 31 Jan 20:00:01 UTC 2017
>
> Ping: xx.xxx ms
>
> Download: xx.xx Mbit/s
>
> Upload: xx.xx Mbit/s

And it continues....
So every line has a piece of data and each 4 lines (Date, ping, download, upload) are one "group".

In your code, you have:

```
$arrEx = explode('\n',fgets($f));
```

> fgets - returns a line.

So you're actually doing:

1 round of the loop: `$arrEx = explode('\n', "Tue 31 Jan 20:00:01 UTC 2017");`

2 round of the loop: `$arrEx = explode('\n', "Ping: xx.xxx ms");` 
...
...

What you should do is:

```
    $arr_to_insert = array();
    $line = 1;    
// Read line by line until end of file
    while (!feof($f)) { 
       if($line == 1){
          $group = array();
       }

       $group[] = fgets($f);


       if($line == 4){
         echo '<tr><td name="date">' . $group[0] . '</td><td name="ping">' . $group[1] . '</td><td name="download">' . $group[2] . '</td><td name="upload">' . $group[3] . '</td></tr>';

         //reset lines group
         $arr_to_insert[] = $group;
         $line = 1;
         unset($group);
       } else {
         $line++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great. And thank you for the explanation too; I wasn't treating the data as a group but each line as a line.